# Discord.js: on('interactionCreate') not working but 'messageCreate' does work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on the commands of the bot and I can't seem to find the solution to my problem. When I run my

```
client.on('messageCreate', async interaction =>{
  // somethingHappens
})
```

It works perfectly, but when I do

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction =>{
  // nothingHappens
})
```

This are my client Intents:

```
[
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES
]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey! Can we see more of your code? Because at first glance what you sent looks alright, secondly interactionCreate is a default event which is received regardless of intents.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I tried using `Events.InteractionCreate` instead, but it made no difference. I can't understand why `messageCreate` is triggering and not this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this intent for me it worked.

```
Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS
```

Comment: this did not work for me!